# How to make navBar's title located at center?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Because the navigationItem.rightBarButtomItem is customized, it will occupy a big place and the title view won't be on the center.

[image]

For example, I want the "OMG" is located at the center between buttoms of "Home" and "Group".
How to achieve this?

Comment: I'd recommend you find a decent design instead of lumping four buttons into the nav bar.

Comment: I have no right to decide the layout of UI. Only the boss has the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the rightBarButtonItem to Camera and Setting... and add Group Button as subview to the navigation bar.. do some trial and error to adjust the x position for the Group Button....
If you have fix titleView as "OMG" good.. if not then it will be little tricky to position the titleView with longer text but it can be done..

Comment: I solved this problem by little tricky about titleView. The titleView's origin cannot not be modified, but its size can be modified to fit my desired goal.

Answer (score 0):

make the title part of the `navigationItem.rightBarButtomItem`, this seems to be the best way to make sure it is positioned correctly.